# auto tab in C to HTML

Tags: html, c, tabs, indentation

how can I convert auto tabs in C code to html, so it will look neat in html to look aligned. Is it safe just to use 4spaces? but some times, 1tab is not 4 spaces, 1,2, or 3 space only. Pls help, thanks!

```
int x ;             /* comment tab  */
x = 0U ;            /* comment tab  */

if ( Gvar == 3U)    /* comment tab  */
{                   /* comment tab  */
    x++ ;           /* comment tab  */
}                   /* comment tab  */
Gvar = 99U ;        /* comment tab  */

return ( 0 )        /* comment tab  */
```

Comment: you could start by replacing all the <tab> characters with ` &#9;`

Comment: You can wrap it in `<pre>`

Comment: it just happened that the C code I want to convert in html is in tab indentation. after '&#9;' whats next?

Comment: @user3629249: Or set tabwidth to something between `2` and `4` (most ppl I know prefer `4`) like most sane programmers do and use it. If you let your editor replace tabs with spaces is a completely unrelated subject.

Comment: the '&#9;' is the tab,  so nothing else needs to be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously you can't just blithely convert every tab into four spaces. That's not how tabs work. Instead you want each tab character to advance the output position to the next tab stop.

You have basically two options:

#### 1. Specify a CSS `tab-size`:

```css
pre { tab-size: 4; -o-tab-size: 4; -moz-tab-size: 4; }
```

```html
<pre>
int main() {
 return 0;  /* This is a comment */
}
</pre>
```

This is the simplest solution, but unfortunately [the `tab-size` rule isn't recognized by IE or Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-tabsize).

#### 2. Pre-process the source code:

Pipe the C source code through the [`expand` command line utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) to convert all the tabs into spaces. For example:

```
expand -t4 <c_source.c >c_source_with_expanded_tabs.c
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I can use this phrase "Instead you want each tab character to advance the output position to the next tab stop." hmm